# Swap div on link hover - Javascript error in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, swap, defined

I have some code which allows me to hover over a number of links and subsequently replace the content in a specified DIV. It works in most browsers but Firefox gives an error - the error can be 'fixed' by removing the doctype code for the page, but clearly this means there is a massive problem with the code and it's not compliant.

Here is the Javascript:

```
var description = new Array();
description[0] = "Content one";
description[1] = "Content two";
description[2] = "Content three";
```

Each link looks like this, with a different number:

```
<a onMouseOver="FeatureSwap.innerHTML = description[1];">
```

And this is the DIV which has its content changed upon hovering on one of the links:

```
<div id="FeatureSwap">Default content here</div>
```

The error that Firefox throws up is:

```
FeatureSwap is not defined
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Remember to upvote useful answers. And if an answer solves your problem, remember to select it by checking it.

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` is an attribute of an element of the DOM, the Document Object Model.

So you need to first gain access to the element. In your case, the element is the div with id of FeatureSwap.

In the following code, we first look up the element by its ID using a method that is common to most all browsers. Then we set its innerHTML property.

Try

```
<a onMouseOver="document.getElementById('FeatureSwap').innerHTML = description[1];">
```

---

FYI, by removing the doctype declaration you led Firefox to display your page in ["quirks mode"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) rather than the standards-compliant mode. One of the [notable features of quirks mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html) in Firefox is that elements can be accessed by their IDs as if they were variables. For more information see the [WHATWG spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object).

Comment: Absolutely spot on, and very fast response!! Thank you :)

Comment: @Shef: Yeah, I know the feeling! Thank you for the upvote. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<a onMouseOver="document.getElementById('FeatureSwap').innerHTML = description[1];">
```

Comment: Absolutely spot on, and very fast response!! Thank you :)